# Swift - Filtering an array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

Can I have advice on how to filter an array? In this case its the annual solar elevations per hour for a particular location, so the array is in essence the day/hour and the degrees. This is its struct:

```
struct SolarElevationArray:  Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var day: Int
    var hour: Int
    var date: Date
    var elevation: Double
    var animate: Bool = false
}
```

This is declared as:

```
State var solarElevation: [SolarElevationArray] = solarElevationDates
```

Where the array is:

```
static var solarElevationDates : [SolarElevationArray] = []
```

If I want to display everything in a chart then the following works perfectly:

```
ForEach(solarElevation) {item in
                    LineMark(
                        x: 
                        y: 
                        series: 
                    ) 
 }
```

But, if I want to filter the array so I only see day == 123, for example, what is the syntax I should use? My approach below is serially flawed:

```
ForEach(solarElevation.filter { solarElevation.day.contains(Int: 123)}) {item in
```

Comment: let filteredArray = solarElevation.filter { $0.day == 123 } or

let filteredArray = solarElevation.filter(\.day == 123) ?

Comment: I used let filteredArray = solarElevation.filter { $0.day == 123 } which works perfectly.